# How to autoload multiple classes in Laravel 4 application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ioc-container

I’ve created a workbench package in Laravel 4, which is name-spaced and has two directories: **Models** and **Contexts**. Somehow, Laravel is loading my models in my **Models** directory (I have a model in there called `User`), however, it doesn’t know about my classes in the **Contexts** directory.

I want to be able to use my context classes in my app’s controllers without specifying the whole namespace, so I thought I’d add them to Laravel’s IoC container. However, it seems I need to create a façade class for each class I wish to add to the container. This isn’t desirable if I have dozens of context classes, as it would mean creating an equal amount of façade classes too.

Is there a way in Laravel to bulk-add classes to its IoC container?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use one term facades for your classes the laravel way (e.g. `MyModel::someAction()`) then you have to create your facades. but i'd advise not to do so for so many classes.

if your classes inside contexts folder aren't found then you should check your `composer.json` file under the autoload entry or do a `composer dump-autoload -o`.

I'd just DI the classes within the constructor of the class that uses them, so you end up using `$this->myService->someAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer both Laravel 4 and 5.

First, you need to use the bind method `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` class, which serves to register binding in the service container. In the Laravel documentation you will find plenty of examples how to do that, but only for a single binding.

If you take a look a the implementation of bind method [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L171) or just the definition [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.html#method_bind), you will notice that this method accepts a `string|array`. This means you can provide multiple bindings as an array and register all of them in the container with their fully qualified class names. Something like this:

```php
$this->app->bind(['\App\Acme\Service1', '\App\Acme\Service2', '\App\Acme\Service3', ...]
```

Having this in mind, you can easily get the classes in one namespace (directory) with a reflection, put them in array and use the above method to register them.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this question some time later, I think the appropriate solution would be to autoload the classes using my package’s **composer.json** file, and then import classes using it’s FQN in controllers and other classes:

```php
<?php

use Vendor\Package\Contexts\ContextClass;

class Laravel4Controller extends BaseController {

    protected $context;

    public function __construct(ContextClass $context) {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

}
```